# "grep -q" vs "if [ -n/-z]"

Tags: shell-script, shell, grep, posix

Hi I have a small wrapper script for NetworkManager which works with dmenu, I want it to be as simple as possible and hopefully fully posix.

I'm using shellcheck and it gives me a "warnig" about this line:

```bsh
...
if [ -z "$(echo "$VAR" | grep "pattern")" ] && [ -z "$(grep -w $OtherVar ~/somefile)" ]
...
```

It (shellcheck) says that I should use `grep -q` instead of `[ -z ]` but after reading (and re-reading) both man pages for bash and grep it doesn't seem like `grep -q` is actually what I want to use, or is it? And how does `grep -q` actually compares to `[ -z/-n]`?

Comment: shellcheck usually gives a rationale why a statement was considered an error or a warning. What did that reason say?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Putting the condition on `[ -z "$(echo "$VAR" | grep "pattern")" ]` checks if the output from `grep` is empty or not. Using `grep -q` checks if grep matched anything.

If you want to know if `$var` contains the regex `$pattern`, you can use

```
if echo "$var" | grep -qe "$pattern"; then
    echo match
fi
```

or `if ! echo ...` for the inverse case.

That's strictly not the same as looking at the output of `grep`, since you might theoretically have a pattern that matches a zero-character string... (but then it would likely match on any input ever.)

Note that there's no `[`..`]` there, we're using that `echo | grep` pipeline directly as the condition. `if command` checks the exit status of *command*, which can be `[`, or another command.

Comment: I didn't know that you can "invert" a if statement, that's probably what I need. I will test it and see if it has any issues

Comment: Ok this seems to work right. I also learned that it isn't inverting the whole if statement but the output of the command itself so I ended up with this: `if ! echo "$VAR" | grep "pattern" && ! grep -xq $OtherVar ~/somefile`. And I also swapped `grep -w` to `grep -xq`

Comment: @user419050, yes `!` inverts a single command or a pipeline, but doesn't take effect past `&&` or `||` (or `;` or `&`). You could group it with braces or parenthesis, so `! false && echo hey` prints `hey`; and `! ( true && echo ho )` prints `ho`, but gives a falsy exit status.

Comment: Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 6):

As per the [wiki](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2143)

`[ -z "$( grep -w  ..) ]` This grep will iterate the entire file and read all matching lines into memory before making a decision.

`grep -q` is cleaner and stops at the first matching line, avoiding both iterating the rest of the directory and reading data into memory.

Comment: And even if you stop `grep` on its first match (using a non-standard extension like `-m`), `grep` still has to output a full line, the shell has to capture it, and then check if it is an empty string. That's far more work than simply having `grep` tell you directly if a match was found or not, without producing *any* output.